# tables, RTF editor in polymer

Tags: dart, rtf, dart-webui, polymer, web-component

I started to use polymer in a dart environment.
Now I would like to create elements like "GWT cell table" or "GWT RichTextArea".

In the polymer elements I cann´t find widgets like this.

Do I have to implement these manually or are the other (higher?) libraries for widgets like this.

Thank Mica

Answer (score 1):

Polymer is still young. More custom elements will emerge as Polymer matures. 
We are currently porting polymer-elements/polymer-ui-elements to Dart. 
Polymer (JS) has more elements in the works (i.e. https://github.com/Polymer/more-elements?files=1).
There are also several projects on github that work on all kinds of additional custom elements. 
I haven't seen elements such as you request though. 
Building one is a very good way to learn what Polymer can do.